# Tableau conditional formatting for number type in same row

Tags: tableau-api

I am looking to format set numbers in a Tableau column to be different based on the row title.

For example I have 1 column that contains both $ and % in the raw data.  and need them to format accordingly.
I was hoping there was something I could use like"

```
Case
When measure = "Sales" then $
When measure = "Percent" then %
When measure = "Total" then $
End
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.  I have been told we can't turn it into string so that won't help.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: could you provide an example of what the values are e.g. is the percent in a decimal as 0.5 and you are wanting to display it as 50%? What are you trying to acheive (data transformation or axis labels?)

Comment: Trying to achieve the label after the number.  I am already doing a data transform to make it 50 the raw data comes in as 0.50.  However the percent is only on a couple of rows.

Comment: and how are you display the data? i..e is the label for a bar graph/text table

Comment: It is in a text table- sorry would attach but working on my partner's machine and don't have the file.

I tried a conversion to string and do a concatenate but ended up with some extraneous data showing up.
The raw data only has 4 decimal places.  However when I concatenate the number carries out to 8 decimal places and adds a 5 at the end:

50.15000005% 

No clue why this is happening- using Tableau 10.13

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855267/tableau-display-different-number-formats-for-the-same-measure) might be helpful if you anyway want to have a forceful formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final calculation I came up with is this one:

```
If attr([Kpi Nm]) = "Policy Retention Better-than-State Average"
    Then str(round(sum([Actual]) * 100, 2)) + "%"
ElseIf attr([Kpi Nm]) = "Policy Retention Improvement (or > 90%)**"
    Then str(round(sum([Actual]) * 100, 2)) + "%"
Elseif attr([Kpi Nm]) = "Premium Growth"
    Then str(round(sum([Actual]) *100, 2)) + "%"
Elseif attr([Kpi Nm]) = "PIF Growth"
    Then str(round(sum([Actual]), 2))
Elseif attr([Kpi Nm]) = "Product Density"
    Then "NA"
else
   STR(ROUND(LOOKUP(sum([Actual]),0),0))
End
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the tableau calculation to have percentage & total instead of this kind of forced formatting.

I would recommend below steps:

1. to have '$' appended to your Sales figure you simply need to change
   the data types of measure column (right click measure ->
   `Default Properties` -> `Number Format` -> select `Currency (Standard)` &
   Locale as `English (United States)`; You should have similar flow in your version of Tableau as this is according to v10.4).
2. drag 'row title' dimension in 'Filters' section to have only 'Sales' row selected ('Total' & 'Percentage' row from your raw data will be ignored by this).
3. now calculate Percentage & Total using tableau calculation.

This will automatically put $ and % in your tabular view without converting the measures to dimension.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option of using the calculation in Tableau- the data I am given is already calculated out, and they won't let me recalculate.  I was also being a little generic on the %, it is not just % of sales or % of growth there are other %s.

Comment: In that case I believe there is no way but to create a calculated field (<string> type) using if-else loop and use it instead of the measure field. BTW as per your specific use case why don't you want to use <string> type if you are are not doing any calculation in tableau but only using the already calculated values to display numbers in desired format?

Comment: I have decided to use a string.  I was told to leave it a number if possible, but it is what I have to do.